# Delete Line before and after found pattern

Tags: sed

I have a configuration that is disabled because its embedded in a comment.
My Sed is deleting the line beneath my pattern, but the line with the pattern gets deleted too. Can I tell Sed to keep the current line? Or just delete the line before and after the found pattern.

Input

```
...
<!--
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
-->
...
```

Sed

```
# sed -e '/<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP\/1.3" redirectPort="8443" \/>/,+2d' server.xml
```

Output

```
...
<!--
...
```

Wish to be Output:

```
...
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
...
```

Comment: Your config seems to be an XML document. Use a proper XML parser to process it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input seems to be an XML document. Use a proper parser to process it. For example, [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open server.xml ;
for my $c in //comment()[contains(.,'<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />')]
    xinsert chunk $c replace $c ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: I have no idea if your snippet is correct, but this is the correct approach. +1

Comment: @DanFego: Thanks. I tested it on a server.xml I created myself, as no sample input file was given. :-)

Comment: Using the right tool for the right job is hardly one ever wants. `:P`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/\n<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP\/1.3" redirectPort="8443" \/>/{s/.*\n//p;$!N;d};P;D' file
```

Keep 2 lines in the pattern space and delete the first, print the next and delete the following line if the pattern is found.